# What does "?>" mean in a PCRE regex?

Tags: php, regex

I can't seem to figure out what `?>` is used for in a regular expression. For example, the following:

```
(?>[^()]+)
```

I know that `?:` means that it shouldn't store the match if you're not going to back reference  the match. Is this somehow related?

Is this also related to a regular expression? `(?P>name)` or `(?&name)`

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php

Comment: Once-only-subexpression http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.onlyonce.php

Comment: Or "Atomic Grouping": http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html

Comment: +1 it's often hard to find simple and comprehensive Regex documentation, let alone the difficulty to include regex syntax in search engines.

Comment: Thanks guys, both sites seem to be very helpful. Could you please give it as an answer so i can atleast upvote the answer and accept one. Thanks.

Comment: @caiosm1005, I recommend Perl's regex documentation.  It is a single page (easy to search for weird expressions in your browser) and it is the standard on which nearly all regex engines are based. It does have some Perl-only features (under "Extended patterns" mainly) but it is a good starting point. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: @dan1111: Here's a link to the relevant section: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f%3epattern)

Comment: @dan1111 Thanks, i didn't know about that site yet. I always google my "regex questions" and i usually end up in php.net, SO or regular-expressions.info. But that's a real usefull site. Was able to find the relevant section in seconds.

Comment: Note that each flavors has it quirk. It is best to refer to the documentation for the specific language when you need some exclusive features, or Unicode support (Unicode support is quite different among the implementations).

Comment: PHP uses internally PCRE library to implement all `preg_*` functions so it would be worth fully reading this someday: https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`(?>pattern)` prevents backtracking on `pattern`. It has at least 2 names: *non-backtracking group*, *atomic group*. I will refer to it as *non-backtracking group*, since it is the most descriptive name.

The expression `(?>[^()]+)` alone doesn't need to be made non-backtracking, though. There is nothing that can induce a backtrack to show non-backtracking behavior.

A more interesting example would be the regex `^\((?>[^()]+)\)`, matching against the string `(a + b()`, compare to the normal version without the non-backtracking group `^\([^()]+\)`.

The normal version, after trying `(a + b` for `^\([^()]+` and fail to match literal `)` will backtrack by one character and retry with `(a +`, etc. until `(a`, where it fails after exhausting all possibilities.

The non-backtracking version will fail the match right after its first try with `(a + b`.

Non-backtracking group is mostly useful to reduce backtracking induced by quantifiers (`?`, `*`, `+`, `{n,}`, `{n,m}`). The trick to optimization with non-backtracking group is to know the first try made by the regex engine. You may need to shift the regex around to make sure the first try made by the engine is what you want to match - then it can be made non-backtracking.

As an example of optimization with non-backtracking group:

- [How can I improve the performance of a .NET regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392132/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-a-net-regular-expression/15393555#15393555)

  The question I quote is from .NET, but it uses the same syntax for non-backtracking group.

  In the question above, the original regex has many usages of `*` and `+` quantifiers. It induces unnecessary backtracking when the match fails, which affect the performance on large input.
- [StackOverflowError when matching large input using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082010/stackoverflowerror-when-matching-large-input-using-regex/15084428#15084428)

  Another example. Note that *possessive* quantifier (adding `+` after normal quantifier, e.g. `?+`, `++`, `*+`, etc.) and non-backtracking group has the same behavior of non-backtracking, just the syntax of non-backtracking group allows it to be generalized.

  You won't get stack overflow in PHP like in Java, but the performance should be better when you validate a long string.

Comment: `(a + b()` should be `(a + b)`

Comment: @Decula: It's an example to show how the regex fails to match the string - it fails immediately with the non-backtracking group, while the normal regex will need to backtrack before failing.

Comment: @Decula Way to completely miss the point